# Force contents of DIV not to wrap

Tags: css, html

I have a DIV defined thusly:

```
<div id="divContent" class="content" style="margin-left:239px;min-height: 100%; padding: 130px 80px 30px 80px; overflow: hidden;">
```

The contents of the div are complex and varied, including lots of different html and css. All I want is to force the contents of the div NOT to wrap, so that as you drag the right edge of the browser window in toward the left edge, content may disappear off the right side, but never wrap.

I have already tried applying this CSS on the divContent div, and also on sub-divs inside divContent, but it did nothing:

```
white-space: nowrap
```

What options do I have?

<< EDIT >>

Here's the actual [web page](http://test.fit-track.net/_test.html).

Here's how it looks (correctly) before making the page smaller:

[image]

Here's how it looks (wrongly) after making the page smaller, and it starts wrapping:

[image]

Comment: You have to add width.

Comment: I just added width, both % and absolute; no change.

Comment: Please try to remove: `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow:hidden` to the element's style, will cause any text that would have flowed out of the div to be hidden.  you should remove it and replace it with `white-space:nowrap`

```
<div id="divContent" class="content" 
     style="margin-left:239px;min-height: 100%; 
            padding: 130px 80px 30px 80px; white-space:nowrap;">
```

Comment: I added a link to the actual page + screenshots, to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for adding a link to the code. My, do you you have a lot of stuff in that div? (It always helps to give the full picture with a question!) And that's the problem - specifically the label/input field pairs. These are inside dd elements, which are inside a div with class = column-thirds. That has a percentage width, which means they shrink as the window shrinks.

But there is nothing to stop the input fields dropping under their labels as the columns shrink in width. So that's what you need to stop. Adding nowrap to their containing elements (the DD elements), and a width as well to stop the label and field overflowing the end of the DD element, should do it:

```
dd { 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width : 400px; /* choose your width here to be wider than the label + field */
}
```

to stop these items wrapping. (And check there is no float property on the labels or input fields, which might also be part of the problem).

[Further edit]

Unfortunately your setup is rather complicated. So to show the nowrap solution is basically correct: do a  small test, with a bank page containing just one of your label field pairs:

```
<dl><dd>
    <label for="txtFirstName" id="lblFirstName" title="First Name" data-required="true">First Name</label>
    <input name="txtFirstName" type="text" value="Frankie8" id="txtFirstName" data-capture="DLFirstName" style="width:131px" />
</dd></dl>
```

and some CSS:

```
dd {
    margin-left: 400px;
    border:2px solid black; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then narrow your window until the right window margin overlaps the field, then comment out the white-space line; you'll see the field drop down under the label. (I've tried it, it works as expected). Hopefully that shows what the basic problem to solve is.

However, looking through your CSS files I see you have a media query in the LESS file Style.less (look for @media around line 1976), that redefines labels as block elements, using display: block. That stops the above nowrap solution working. Labels are normally inline elements. So either you need to be able to get rid of that display change if you can, or find another solution.

An alternative solution would be to give the  containing divs (the class = column-thirds ones), a min-width to stop them shrinking so much they cause your wrapping problem in the first place. The only other thing I can think of might be floating the labels, but I wouldn't like to bet how that would turn out.

I hope this all helps you obtain a suitable fix for your problem.

Comment: I added that style on the test page. It made no difference.

Comment: Ok, I've had a further look through your CSS files and I can see what is stopping that solution. There is a media query in the LESS file Style.less, and that redefines labels as block elements, which clobbers that solution. I've edited my earlier solution accordingly. You can either stop that display redefine, or I've also suggested an alternative way.

Comment: Sounds promising, but what is the CSS to override the redefine labels as block elements? What exactly would I add in the page to override that style coming from the css? Also, min-width didn't help, but maybe it has to work in conjunction with the override?

Comment: Do some testing first to check the solution. Comment out the display:block line of the media query temporarily, and add my nowrap solution on the DD element, and see if your problem is solved then. If it is, then at least you know there's nothing else gumming up the works that we havent spotted. Of course, getting rid of the display line might cause something else to go wrong. You'll just have to try it and see. Most importantly, if it doesn't work, add a comment to show us what you did, so people can get a chance to see why it might not have worked.

Comment: GuyH, this is progress. Please look at my test page now. You'll see that as the window gets dragged smaller, at some point the labels and textboxes sort of collapse together and become uneven. It looks terrible, but at least it doesn't wrap like it used to. If you could show me (1) how to fix the "uneven" problem and (2) how to override that media block style in the page, I would be most grateful. I can't risk changing that media block style permanently in the less file because it could impact many other pages, and I only need the behavior change on this 1 page. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, we've confirmed that it is the display: block that is the problem, and that there is nothing else affecting it. Now change that line to display:inline-block; that should do it.

Comment: As to your concern about other pages, you just need the CSS to identify which page it's on. How much CSS do you know? Add an id to something, like the fieldset containing the fields & labels, but only do it on this page. Then have two display lines inside that media query, the original display:block one unchanged, and one for just this page, that includes the id: fieldset { ... display:block; ... }  fieldset#myId { display:inline-block; }. (No need to repeat all the css for the fieldset, just the one display line, to give it a different value to override the one from the original setting.)

Comment: GuyH, thanks for your tenacity on this. "display:inline-block" sort of fixed it, but had the same result as removing the style altogether: everything collapses and the columns don't align anymore. I'm beginning to think my styles and html are too complex and messy for any silver bullet. I may need to just rewrite the whole page to html tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width to the size you want the div to be, in px units, e.g.:

```
... width: 500px; ...
```

Then, if the screen gets narrower than that, the div will disappear off the right of the screen as required, regardless of the overflow setting. 
It often helps in problems like this to give all the divs borders temporarily, eg with:     border 1px solid red;  so you can see what's happening.

Overflow only comes into play if you fix both the width and height of the div, and the text is too long to fit in that box - it will then spread down below the div. White-space looks as though it works, because it makes the text stick to one line, until you give the div a border and realise that the div still ends at the edge of the screen (however wide that may be at any given moment) and the text now extends beyond the end of the div (which you can see if you add the border, and remove the overflow hidden).

So fixing the width of the div, if done right, should work (I've used 500px, but change that to whatever you want):

```
<div id="divContent" class="content" style="width: 500px; margin-left:239px;min-height: 100%; padding: 130px 80px 30px 80px; overflow: hidden;">
```

However, a lot depends on what content you have in your div, and what CSS they have, so if fixing the width like this doesn't work, give us those as well, please.

Comment: The contents of the div still wrap.

Comment: I added a link to the actual page + screenshots, to the original post.

Comment: Per your comment below...sounds promising, but what is the CSS to override the redefine labels as block elements? What exactly would I add in the page to override that style coming from the css?